# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT] error while sideloading app on Fire TV Stick

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, amazon-fire-tv

My app works fine when I install the app via Android Studio, but when I try to sideload the app using adb, I get the `INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT` error. I have tried many things like cleaning, invalidating etc. but everything failed.

This only happens on the Fire TV Sticks with OS version 5.1.1, contrarily on the Fire TV regardless of the OS (even on 5.1.1 Fire TV), the app works absolutely ok.

Gradle version: **4.4** (Going back to 4.1 didn't help)
Android Plugin Version: **3.1.2** (Going back to 3.0.1 didn't help)
Build Tool Version: **27.0.3**
minSdkVersion: **21**
compileSdkVersion: **26**
targetSdkVersion: **26**

I am assuming this is the reason why my build isn't getting installed on the lollipop devices when I install the Live App Testing app.

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Logcat output attached: https://gist.github.com/anas-incedo/64992269a1734061a2f739a5887e809c

Comment: this is related to Amazon FireTV device. So you can also post this question on Amazon developer forum.

Comment: @nitintyagi, thanks for the suggestion. Here is the question I asked on Amazon forums. https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/170776/failure-install-failed-dexopt-error-while-sideload.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set com.android.tools.build:gradle: to 3.0.1  and gradle to 4.4 solve my issue. Try it.

Comment: You might also need to upgrade the gradle plugin to 3.1.3 or higher, I still had the error with 3.1.2
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to lie, at least for me; in the gradle version. When i moved back from gradle 4.4 to 4.1 and set com.android.tools.build:gradle: to 3.0.1 i was able to install my application. This will suffice in the short term but this issue needs to be addressed.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I did try using 4.1 and 3.0.1, but still getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this same issue when upgrading my gradle plugin from 3.0.1 to 3.1.2.

It seems that upgrading now to 3.1.4 seems to have solved the issue.

Prior to 3.1.4 release, what I did to get around that was set the gradle.properties with `android.enableD8=false`. Now it seems I can remove the work around.